Proving Properties of PGF's
I am trying to understand why the following properties of a Probability Generating Function (for a discrete random variable $X$) are true:
$$
G_X(s) = \mathbb{E}[s^X] = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} p_k s^k
$$

Property 1: $ G(1) = 1 $

I think this one is straightforward:
$ G_X(1) $ is given by:
$$
  G_X(1) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} p_k \cdot 1^k = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} p_k
  $$
Since $ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} p_k = 1 $ (the sum of all probabilities equals 1),
$$
  G_X(1) = 1
  $$
Thus, $ G(1) = 1 $.

Property 2: $ G'(1) = \mathbb{E}[X] $

This one requires taking the derivative (naturally)
The first derivative of the PGF with respect to $ s $ is:
$$
  G'_X(s) = \frac{d}{ds} \left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} p_k s^k\right) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} p_k \cdot k \cdot s^{k-1}
  $$
Evaluating at $ s = 1 $, we get:
$$
  G'_X(1) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} p_k \cdot k \cdot 1^{k-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k \cdot p_k
  $$
This is the definition of the expected value of $ X $, so:
$$
  G'(1) = \mathbb{E}[X]
  $$

Property 3: $ G''(1) = \mathbb{E}[X(X-1)] $
The second derivative of the PGF with respect to $ s $ is:
$$
  G''_X(s) = \frac{d^2}{ds^2} \left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} p_k s^k\right) = \frac{d}{ds} \left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} p_k \cdot k \cdot s^{k-1}\right) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} p_k \cdot k \cdot (k-1) \cdot s^{k-2}
  $$
Evaluating this at $ s = 1 $, we get:
$$
  G''_X(1) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} p_k \cdot k \cdot (k-1) \cdot 1^{k-2} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k(k-1) \cdot p_k
  $$
This is the expectation of $ X(X-1) $, so:
$$
  G''(1) = \mathbb{E}[X(X-1)]
  $$

Property 4: $ \text{Var}(X) = G''(1) + G'(1) - [G'(1)]^2 $
This one I did using first principles (i.e. definition of variance using expected values).


The variance $ \text{Var}(X) $ is given by:
$$
  \text{Var}(X) = \mathbb{E}[X^2] - (\mathbb{E}[X])^2
  $$
We can express $ \mathbb{E}[X^2] $ in terms of the PGF:
$$
  \mathbb{E}[X^2] = \mathbb{E}[X(X-1)] + \mathbb{E}[X] = G''(1) + G'(1)
  $$
Thus, the variance becomes:
$$
  \text{Var}(X) = G''(1) + G'(1) - [G'(1)]^2
  $$
Have I done all this correctly?

Yes, this is all fine. Didn't you ask this already?

@ Qiaochu: Can you please take a look at this question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4957479/number-of-coin-flips-before-a-certain-condition-is-reached
