Number of Coin Flips Before a Certain Condition is Reached?
I am working on the following problem:

Coin 1: Probability of heads = $p_1$, score for heads = $s_1$, score for tails = $s_2$
Coin 2: Probability of heads = $p_2$, score for heads = $s_3$, score for tails = $s_4$
We flip both coins at the same time and record the score at each round (we start with a score of 0)

I want to find the probability distribution for the number of flips needed for the total score to exceed some value $c$.
I think PGFs are a good choice for this problem. Here is my attempt to work on it:
Part 1: Let $ X_i $ be the score obtained on the $ i $-th flip and let $ X_i $ can be the result of either flipping Coin 1 or Coin 2. The score distribution is determined by which coin is used and whether it lands on heads or tails.

For Coin 1:

If heads, score = $ s_1 $ with probability $ p_1 $.
If tails, score = $ s_2 $ with probability $ 1 - p_1 $.
The PGF for a single flip of Coin 1, $ G_{X_1}(z) $, is:
$$
   G_{X_1}(z) = p_1 \cdot z^{s_1} + (1 - p_1) \cdot z^{s_2}
  $$


For Coin 2:

If heads, score = $ s_3 $ with probability $ p_2 $.
If tails, score = $ s_4 $ with probability $ 1 - p_2 $.
The PGF for a single flip of Coin 2, $ G_{X_2}(z) $, is:
$$
   G_{X_2}(z) = p_2 \cdot z^{s_3} + (1 - p_2) \cdot z^{s_4}
  $$



Part 2: I defined first passage time $ T_c $ as the number of flips needed to reach or exceed a score of $c$ for the firs time. I tried to pick up on a pattern.

Case: 1 Flip

After one flip, the total score $ S_1 $ could either be greater than $ c $ or not. The probability that $ T_c = 1 $ (i.e., we reach or exceed $ c $ in exactly one flip) is:
$$
 \mathbb{P}(T_c = 1) = \mathbb{P}(S_1 > c)
  $$
The PGF for $ T_c $ in this case would just be:
$$
 G_{T_c}(z) = \mathbb{P}(T_c = 1) \cdot z^1
  $$

Case: 2 Flips (i.e. 2 or less)
For $ T_c = 2 $ to occur, the first flip must result in a score $ S_1 $ that does not exceed $ c $, and then the total score after the second flip must exceed $ c $.This can be written as:
$$
 \mathbb{P}(T_c = 2) = \sum_{s=0}^{c} \mathbb{P}(S_1 = s) \cdot \mathbb{P}(S_2 > c - s)
  $$
The corresponding PGF contribution is:
$$
 G_{T_c}(z) = \mathbb{P}(T_c = 1) \cdot z + \mathbb{P}(T_c = 2) \cdot z^2
  $$

Case: 3 Flips (i.e. 3 or less)
For $ T_c = 3 $ to occur:

The first flip must not exceed $ c $, i.e., the score $ S_1 \leq c $.

After two flips, the total score must still be less than or equal to $ c $, i.e., $ S_2 \leq c - s $ for each possible $ S_1 = s $.
Finally, after the third flip, the score must exceed $ c $.
The probability for this is:
$$
 \mathbb{P}(T_c = 3) = \sum_{s_1=0}^{c} \mathbb{P}(S_1 = s_1) \sum_{s_2=0}^{c-s_1} \mathbb{P}(S_2 = s_2) \cdot \mathbb{P}(S_3 > c - (s_1 + s_2))
  $$
The PGF contribution would then be:
$$
 G_{T_c}(z) = \mathbb{P}(T_c = 1) \cdot z + \mathbb{P}(T_c = 2) \cdot z^2 + \mathbb{P}(T_c = 3) \cdot z^3
  $$




General Case for $ n $ Flips: (i.e. n or less)
$$
 \mathbb{P}(T_c = n) = \sum_{s_1=0}^{c} \mathbb{P}(S_1 = s_1) \sum_{s_2=0}^{c-s_1} \cdots \sum_{s_{n-1}=0}^{c-\sum_{i=1}^{n-2} s_i} \mathbb{P}(S_{n-1} = s_{n-1}) \cdot \mathbb{P}(S_n > c - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} s_i)
  $$
$$
 G_{T_c}(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(T_c = n) \cdot z^n
  $$


Part 3: I then tried to test this for $c=1$
For $ c = 0 $, no flips are needed, so:
$$
G_{T_0}(z) = 1
$$
This corresponds to $ \mathbb{P}(T_0 = 0) = 1 $.
For $ c = 1 $, we expand the generating function:
$$
G_{T_1}(z) = z \cdot \sum_{s=0}^{1} \mathbb{P}(S_1 = s) \cdot G_{T_{1-s}}(z)
$$
Substitute the base case $ G_{T_0}(z) = 1 $:
$$
G_{T_1}(z) = z \cdot \left[\mathbb{P}(S_1 = 0) \cdot G_{T_1}(z) + \mathbb{P}(S_1 = 1) \cdot 1\right]
$$
$$
G_{T_1}(z) = z \cdot \mathbb{P}(S_1 = 1) + z \cdot \mathbb{P}(S_1 = 0) \cdot G_{T_1}(z)
$$
$$
G_{T_1}(z) - z \cdot \mathbb{P}(S_1 = 0) \cdot G_{T_1}(z) = z \cdot \mathbb{P}(S_1 = 1)
$$
$$
G_{T_1}(z) \cdot (1 - z \cdot \mathbb{P}(S_1 = 0)) = z \cdot \mathbb{P}(S_1 = 1)
$$
$$
G_{T_1}(z) = \frac{z \cdot \mathbb{P}(S_1 = 1)}{1 - z \cdot \mathbb{P}(S_1 = 0)}
$$
We can also rely on the classical geometric series identity to further simplify:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r^n = \frac{1}{1 - r} \quad \text{for} \quad |r| < 1
$$
$$
\frac{1}{1 - z \cdot \mathbb{P}(S_1 = 0)} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(z \cdot \mathbb{P}(S_1 = 0)\right)^n
$$
Thus:
$$
G_{T_1}(z) = \frac{z \cdot \mathbb{P}(S_1 = 1)}{1 - z \cdot \mathbb{P}(S_1 = 0)} = z \cdot \mathbb{P}(S_1 = 1) \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (z \cdot \mathbb{P}(S_1 = 0))^n
$$
Part 4: We can use the above expression to extract probabilities (e.g. probability of exceeding a score of 1 in $k$ flips)
$$
G_{T_1}(z) = \frac{z \cdot \mathbb{P}(S_1 = 1)}{1 - z \cdot \mathbb{P}(S_1 = 0)} = z \cdot \mathbb{P}(S_1 = 1) \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (z \cdot \mathbb{P}(S_1 = 0))^n
$$
$$
G_{T_1}(z) = \mathbb{P}(S_1 = 1) \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^{n+1} \cdot (\mathbb{P}(S_1 = 0))^n
$$
$$
G_{T_1}(z) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} z^k \cdot \mathbb{P}(S_1 = 1) \cdot (\mathbb{P}(S_1 = 0))^{k-1}
$$
Remember that the coefficient of the exponent corresponds to the probability:
$$
\mathbb{P}(T_1 = k) = \mathbb{P}(S_1 = 1) \cdot (\mathbb{P}(S_1 = 0))^{k-1}
$$
Part 5: I wanted to take it a bit further and discuss expected values and variances.
In general we know that (Proving Properties of PGF's, Connection between Taylor Series and Probabilities, Relationship between PGFs and Moments?):
$$
\mathbb{E}[T_c] = G_{T_c}'(1)
$$
In this question, we can write:
$$
G_{T_1}(z) = \frac{z \cdot \mathbb{P}(S_1 = 1)}{1 - z \cdot \mathbb{P}(S_1 = 0)}
$$
$$
G_{T_1}'(z) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(S_1 = 1) \cdot (1 - z \cdot \mathbb{P}(S_1 = 0)) - z \cdot \mathbb{P}(S_1 = 1) \cdot (-\mathbb{P}(S_1 = 0))}{(1 - z \cdot \mathbb{P}(S_1 = 0))^2}
$$
$$
G_{T_1}'(z) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(S_1 = 1) \cdot [1 - z \cdot \mathbb{P}(S_1 = 0) + z \cdot \mathbb{P}(S_1 = 0)]}{(1 - z \cdot \mathbb{P}(S_1 = 0))^2} = \frac{\mathbb{P}(S_1 = 1)}{(1 - z \cdot \mathbb{P}(S_1 = 0))^2}
$$
$$
G_{T_1}'(1) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(S_1 = 1)}{(1 - \mathbb{P}(S_1 = 0))^2} = \frac{\mathbb{P}(S_1 = 1)}{(\mathbb{P}(S_1 = 1))^2} = \frac{1}{\mathbb{P}(S_1 = 1)}
$$
$$
\mathbb{E}[T_1] = \frac{1}{\mathbb{P}(S_1 = 1)}
$$
The variance can be defined as:
$$
\text{Var}(T_c) = G_{T_c}''(1) + G_{T_c}'(1) - [G_{T_c}'(1)]^2
$$
And in general, the Probability Mass Function:
$$
\mathbb{P}(T_c = n) = \frac{1}{n!} \left. \frac{d^n}{dz^n} G_{T_c}(z) \right|_{z=0}
$$
Conclusion: Can someone please help me confirm if I have the correct understanding?

(1) Are $s_1$ through $s_4$ non-negative integers? Does the support of $S_1$ contain exactly 4 values or less than 4 values? (2) How was part 1 used later? For deriving PGF of $S_1$? (3) Is the purpose of part 2 to derive the last expression in that part? (4) At the end of part 4, why isn't it $P(S_1\geq1)[P(S_k=0)]^{k-1}$?

@ Ryan Shen: Thank you for your reply! For 1) I was assuming that S1 and S2 are positive ... for simplicity, I was thinking to allow the smallest increase in score to be 0.1 .... but now after rethinking everything ... I think it might be easier to keep S1 and S2 are positive integers

Re 2) ... this was part of my original notes ... looking back, I never ended up directly using it...


The purpose of the problem was to derive the probability distribution for the "hitting time".  I am really interested in learning about probability distributions for the first hitting time/first passage time of stochastic processes and wanted to try and solve this problem using PGFs


Does it affect anything later on if we just keep the last expression in part 2? Or did you use the earlier special cases in part 2 to get the recurrence relation in part 3? I can get your general route of thought, but I'm somewhat lost in the details.

@ Ryan : I think we skip that part and go directly towards the end of 2. I think I really botched this whole problem and made it too convoluted and complicated. If you have time, maybe you could please show me how to approach this problem correctly?

Please stop spamming links to this question on unrelated questions.

@ Misha Lavrov: Sorry, my apologies

My take would be Brownian motion approximation to this, since the increments are independent. If it take a relative large number of steps to reach a threshold, the approximation would reasonable.

@ Ryan: Hi Ryan, any chance you can write an answer to this?

Are you assuming that the $s_k$ are natural numbers, or could they be any real value?

@ Brian : Thank you ... lets assume they are natural numbers to keep it simple?

My attempt is only a continuous approximation to the question:
For each round $i$, the increment in score $R_i$ has a $4$-point distribution with mean and variance $(\mu,\sigma^2)$, where
$$\mu=p_1(s_1-s_2)+p_2(s_3-s_4)+s_2+s_4, \text{ and }\\
\sigma^2=p_1(1-p_1)(s_1-s_2)^2 + p_2(1-p_2)(s_3-s_4)^2.$$
Further define $R_0=0$.
Let the total score after the $t$th round be the cumulative sum
$$X(t)=\sum_{i=0}^t R_i. 
$$
Obviously, $X(t)$ has independent increment and $$\mathbb{E}[X(t)]=t\mu, \\
\mathbb{V}\mathrm{ar}[X(t)]=t\sigma^2, \text{ and}\\
\mathbb{C}\mathrm{ov}[X(t),X(t')]=\min(t,t')\sigma^2.$$
For large $t\longrightarrow\infty$, by CLM, $$\frac{X(t)-t\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{t}} \stackrel{d}{\longrightarrow}\mathcal{N}(0,1).$$
Define the continuous analog by $\tilde{X}(t)=X\left(\left\lfloor t \right\rfloor\right)$ for $t>0$. Because $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \lfloor t \rfloor/t=1$, $\tilde{X}(t)$ is approximately a Brownian motion with drift $\mu$ and diffusion constant $\sigma^2$.
For a given barrier $c>0$, the first cross time $T_c$ for $X(t)$ to reach or exceed $c$ is the same as the first cross time for $\tilde{X}(t)$ to reach or exceed $c$. And for large $c$, this is approximately distributed as the first cross time $\tilde{T}_c$ for BrownMotion($\mu,\sigma^2$) to exceed $c$. But $\tilde{T}_c$ has a known inverse Gaussian distribution, with CDF
$$F_{\tilde{T}_c}(\tilde{t}_c)=I(\tilde{t}_c>0)\left\lbrace
 \Phi\left[ \frac{c}{\sigma\sqrt{\tilde{t}_c}}\left(\frac{\tilde{t}_c\mu}{c} -1 \right)\right] + 
\exp\left(\frac{2\mu c}{\sigma^2}  \right)
\Phi\left[ \frac{c}{\sigma\sqrt{\tilde{t}_c}}\left(\frac{\tilde{t}_c\mu}{c} +1 \right)\right] 
 \right\rbrace.
$$
So for ${t}_c\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, we have $$\mathbb{P}(T_c={t}_c) \approx F_{\tilde{T}_c}({t}_c) -F_{\tilde{T}_c}({t}_c-1).$$

@ Ryan: Thank you so much! I guess this approximation is correct for situations involving a very large number of coin flips, correct?

@wulasa I don't know how large it needs to be. For the normal approximation fo $X(t)$, I know we can use Berry-Esseen bound; but for the inverse Gaussian approximation to $T_c$, I don't know what bound is available.
