Let we are tossing a fair coin repeatedly (infinite tosses), what is the fraction of heads appearing?
How to relate fraction of heads in n tosses to fraction of heads in infinite tosses of a fair coin? And how to relate it to sample space of [0,1]?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Toss the coin $N$ times, $1 \leq N < \infty$, then you will get $n$ heads, $0 \leq n \leq N$. Therefore you will have gotten $N-n$ tails.
Flipping infinitely many times, means $N$ grows without bound. We call that process "in the limit as $N$ approaches infinity", denoted $\lim_{N\to\infty}$.
So if $N$ is finite, the proportion of tosses that are heads and that are tails add to $1$, $$\frac{n}{N} + \frac{N-n}{N} = 1. \quad (*)$$
If $N$ is infinite, the proportion of tosses that are heads and that are tails is defined to be the probability $P$ of heads and tails respectively, and since the coin is fair,
$$ P(heads) = \lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{n}{N} = \lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{N-n}{N} = P(tails). \quad (**)$$
The two equations $(*)$ and $(**)$ imply that
$$P(heads) = \frac{1}{2} = P(tails)$$
To relate it to the unit interval could mean so many things... For example, the infinite coin flips could be represented using an itinerary; an infinitely long binary string, encoding whether at each flip the uniform random number was coming from the interval $[0,1/2]$ or $(1/2,1]$. Or it could be related in the the expected value of uniform random number on unit interval is the midpoint, $1/2$. Or that the center of mass of two equally weighted points is their midpoint. etc.

@ Nazim: great answer! Can you please take a look at this question if possible? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4957479/number-of-coin-flips-before-a-certain-condition-is-reached
