Mathematics of Pizza Eating
While attending a summer bbq with my family, I noticed that when it comes to eating pizza, people eat pizza in different ways.
For a basic problem, assume that people are less likely to eat an additional slice as the total number of slices increase
As a mathematical exercise, I tried to define probability functions to describe this scenario.
Idea 1:
Implicitly, eating the $n^{th}$ slice means that slices from $1,2,3...,n-1$ have already been eaten. Assume that everyone has a probability of 1 for eating the first slice. And for argument sake (although I don't use this here), let's assume that the entire picnic has $Z$ number of slices.
Let $X$ be the random variable representing the number of pizza slices eaten, and $p(n)$ be the probability of eating the $n^{th}$ slice given that $n-1$ slices have already been eaten (note, this is not the probability of eating a maximum of $n$ slices, its just the probability of eating $X=n$ slices):
$$
p(X = n | n-1, n-2, n-3, ...,1) = p_0 \cdot r^{n-1}
$$
Where:

$p_0$ is the initial probability of eating the first slice (usually close to 1)
$r$ is the constant rate at which the probability decreases (0 < $r$ < 1)
$n$ is the number of the current slice

Next, consider the following point on the probability of eating exactly 5 slices. This corresponds to someone who happily ate the first 5 slices and decided to stop.
$$P(X = 5) = P(5|4) \cdot P(4|3) \cdot P(3|2) \cdot P(2|1) \cdot P(1)$$
Now, consider the following point on the probability of not eating the 6th slice. This corresponds to someone who happily ate the first 5 slices, attempted to eat the 6th slice but was too full to continue:
$$P( 6>X>=5) = [1 - P(6|5)] \cdot P(5|4) \cdot P(4|3) \cdot P(3|2) \cdot P(2|1) \cdot P(1)$$
This means I can write:
$$ P(\text{eating first } k \text{ slices}) = \prod_{i=1}^k p(i) = \prod_{i=1}^k (p_0 \cdot r^{i-1}) $$
$$ = p_0 \cdot p_0r \cdot p_0r^2 \cdot ... \cdot p_0r^{k-1} $$
$$ = p_0^k \cdot r^{0+1+2+...+(k-1)} = p_0^k \cdot r^{\frac{k(k-1)}{2}} $$
As a closing example, consider the following point:
$$p(X = 3 | 2,1 ) = p_0 \cdot r^{3-1}$$
$$p(X = 5 |4,3, 2,1 ) = p_0 \cdot r^{5-1}$$
$$P(X = 7|6,5,4,3,2,1) = p_0 \cdot r^{7-1}$$
Looking at the ratios:
$$ \frac{p(X = 5 \mid 4, 3, 2, 1)}{p(X = 3 \mid 2, 1)} = \frac{p_0 \cdot r^{5-1}}{p_0 \cdot r^{3-1}} = \frac{p_0 \cdot r^{4}}{p_0 \cdot r^{2}} = r^2 $$
$$ \frac{p(X = 7 \mid 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)}{p(X = 5 \mid 4, 3, 2, 1)} = \frac{p_0 \cdot r^{7-1}}{p_0 \cdot r^{5-1}} = \frac{p_0 \cdot r^{6}}{p_0 \cdot r^{4}} = r^2 $$
This suggests that someone is $r^2$ times more likely to eat 5 slices vs 3 slices ... yet someone is also $r^2$ times more likely to eat 7 slices vs 5 slices. Considering how the human stomach works, this might not be a very realistic assumption.
Idea 2:
I tried to analyze this same problem a different way. As an example:

Suppose I have eaten 2 slices and my friend has eaten 4 slices. Which of us has a higher probability of eating 2 more slices?
Under my set up, I am more likely to from (2,4) compared to my friend going from (4,6)
Clearly, in general - going from (1,2) is far more likely than going from (9,10) as this is more representative of how the human stomach works. In the first idea, we treated going from (1,2) as equally likely compared from going to (9,10).
Mathematically, this means we will use an (exponential) decay rate compared to the constant rate in the first idea

I tried to characterize this mathematically. Let:
$$
\begin{aligned}
& X: \text{Random variable representing the number of slices eaten} \\
& \mu: \text{Average number of slices eaten} \\
& P(X = i): \text{Probability of eating exactly i slices} \\
& P(X \geq i | X \geq j): \text{Probability of eating i or more slices given j slices already eaten, where i > j}
\end{aligned}
$$
Now, define the conditional probability function $α(i,j)$:
$$
\alpha(i,j) = P(X \geq i | X \geq j) = e^{-\lambda(i-j)} \cdot e^{-\gamma j}
$$
$$\alpha(1,0)  = 1$$
Where:

$λ$ > 0: Controls how quickly the probability decreases for additional slices
$γ$ > 0: Controls how quickly the probability decreases as more slices are eaten

Here, I use the exponential function to represent the decay process. $e^{-x}$ always outputs values between 0 and 1 for positive x, which is suitable for probabilities. This allow us to combine multiple effects multiplicatively.

$e^{-\lambda(i-j)}$: takes into consideration decrease in probability for additional slices.$(i-j)$ represents the number of additional slices beyond $j$. As $(i-j)$ increases, this term decreases, reducing the probability . On the other hand, $λ$ controls how quickly this decrease happens.

$e^{-\gamma j}$ takes into consideration the decrease in probability as more slices have been eaten. As $j$ (slices already eaten) increases, this term decreases. As $γ$ controls how quickly this decrease happens.


The product of these two terms reflects the combined effect:
$$\alpha(i,j) = e^{-\lambda(i-j)} \cdot e^{-\gamma j} = e^{-\lambda(i-j) - \gamma j}$$
As a logical check, we can see that

As $j$ increases (more slices eaten), the probability decreases due to $e^{-\gamma j}$.
As $i$ increases (considering more additional slices), the probability decreases due to $e^{-\lambda(i-j)}$.
The combined effect (multiplication of these terms) ensures that the probability decreases both with more slices eaten and when considering more additional slices.

Putting it all together, the probability of eating exactly k slices is:
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(X = k) &= \prod_{i=1}^k \alpha(i,i-1) \cdot (1 - \alpha(k+1,k)) \\
&= \prod_{i=1}^k (e^{-\lambda} \cdot e^{-\gamma(i-1)}) \cdot (1 - e^{-\lambda} \cdot e^{-\gamma k}) \\
&= e^{-k\lambda} \cdot e^{-\gamma\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} i} \cdot (1 - e^{-\lambda} \cdot e^{-\gamma k}) \\
&= e^{-k\lambda} \cdot e^{-\gamma\frac{k(k-1)}{2}} \cdot (1 - e^{-\lambda} \cdot e^{-\gamma k})
\end{aligned}
$$
Conclusion: Can someone please tell me if my mathematical manipulations and formulations of these ideas are logical?

This is exactly the sort of question I really enjoy. It's possible that Math.SE users will find it too vague and vote to close, but I'm hoping that the question is long enough that that doesn't happen. :-)
Your working through of the framework is reasonable! My own preference is to make as few assumptions as possible in constructing it; more specific situations can then be explored by plugging in specific functions or families of functions.
For instance, I might do something like define
$$
p_k \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} P(\text{eat the $k+1$th slice} \mid
                               \text{ate the $k$th slice})
$$
I might impose only the condition that $p_k$ is decreasing, or possibly only that it's non-increasing. (This would make it possible for $p_k = p_{k+1}$ for some $k$.) This assumption is sufficient to demonstrate that
$$
P(\text{eat $k+j$ slices} \mid \text{eat $k$ slices})
$$
is a decreasing function of $k$ for a given $j$. The probability of eating exactly $k$ slices would be
$$
q_k \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} (1-p_k)\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}p_j
$$
We could use this to derive an expression for the mean number of slices consumed:
$$
E(\text{slices}) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty kq_k
                 = \sum_{k=0}^\infty k(1-p_k)\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}p_j
$$
This telescopes fairly conveniently and becomes the nicer
$$
E(\text{slices}) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \prod_{j=0}^k p_j
                 = p_0 + p_0p_1 + p_0p_1p_2 + p_0p_1p_2p_3 + \cdots
$$
Because $p_k$ is non-increasing, we can now demonstrate
$$
E(\text{slices}) \leq \sum_{k=0}^\infty p_0^{k+1} = \frac{p_0}{1-p_0}
$$
For example, if the probability of eating the first slice is $2/3$, the expected number of slices consumed can be no more than $2$, which equality achieved only if $p_k = 2/3$ for all $k$.
Now, if $p_k$ is itself a geometric sequence—that is, if $p_k = ar^k$ for $a \leq 1, r < 1$—then we can obtain
$$
q_k = a^k(1-ar^k)r^{\frac{k(k-1)}{2}}
$$
The expected number of slices in this case is, I believe,
$$
E(\text{slices}) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a^{k+1}r^{\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}
$$
I don't know offhand a closed-form expression for this sum. Does anyone else?
And so on. One could continue in this vein for quite a while; maybe I'll even do so when I have a bit more time!

@ Brian Tung: Thank you so much for your efforts and time! I hope others will find it interesting as well! I had recently written this question on analyzing a coin flip problem - do you think you can please check if my analysis seems logical to you if you have time? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4957479/number-of-coin-flips-before-a-certain-condition-is-reached ... thank you so much!
